# Delete rows when creating a FK relationship?

Tags: mysql

PK in table A,
but FK relationship wasn't created in table B.

Table B has several entries that point to a PK in table A that has been deleted.

We need to create the FK relationship and would like all rows in table B that do not have a match in table A to be deleted.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the rows in table B that do not have the corresponding PK from table A and delete them accordingly.

You can test this with a JOIN query.

```
SELECT id
FROM foo
RIGHT JOIN bar
ON foo.id = bar.foo_id
WHERE foo.id IS NULL
```

table A - foo
table B - bar